# unzipping files in windows using unzip

Tags: r, unzip

I am having problems unzipping files in R using the `unzip` function. Works find on my Mac, but not on Windows, probably dues to some Path-problems. Here is the path of the file in windows:

```
unzip(zipfile = "\\TRS.hlm.no/home$/username/Documents/example.zip")
```

Error in unzip(zipfile = "\TRS.hlm.no/home$/username/Documents/example.zip")
cannot open file './Out/Code/Code_0012-23.1G-01-02-23:09:09.txt": invalid argument

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: That path looks wrong. Use `file.exists` to check whether the path can be found by R. If this is supposed to be a UNC/network path, you need to add two backslashes to the beginning (a single backslash is an escape character!).

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated question, got the path right now, but maybe some symbols I the filename is causing this new error?

Comment: Make sure 6that the zip file name and file names of the files in the zip file don't use any Windows reserved characters.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file